# Remove first annotation-MapView

Tags: ios, android-mapview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing First Annotation-MapView iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221757/removing-first-annotation-mapview-ios)

I am working on mapview project. I have question to remove annotation from mapview.
Total annotation point would be 5. How could I remove first annotation from my mapView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have got my answer,

```
[mapView removeAnnotation:[self.mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:0]];
```