# Removing First Annotation-MapView iOS

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am working on mapview project. I have question related to removing annotation from the mapView.
I have implemented the following code but it removes annotation randomly, not the first one!

```
[mapView removeAnnotation:[self.mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.mapView.annotations` gives you an NSArray of all the annotations, but it does not promise to be in the same order each time nor in the order you added annotations. You will have to find another way to get a reference to the one you intend to delete.

Comment: `[mapView removeAnnotation:myAnnotation];` But it depends totally on code you haven't shown here how you set `myAnnotation`. Maybe it is the first on you add after your app starts, maybe it is the first result of a search, I have no idea what app code does and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

I have came across a solution. Whomever concerns about this question's answer, there you go

I have created an NSMUtable array and add all objects into array then remove first element from the mapview

```
 [mapView removeAnnotation:[annotationArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```